# Does Flash respect Cache-Control & Expires headers in all browsers?

Tags: php, html, flash, caching, header

I'm working with a Flash .swf file made by someone else for which I do not, and will not ever have the source. I believe it's been developed in Flash 9/AS3 but I'm not sure of this.

The Flash program loads in its settings from an XML file: config.xml. By editing this file I can manually force re-caching of loaded assets (by appending ?uniquestring to URLs in the config file which will be loaded later).

However, the config.xml file is hard-coded and I can't force a query string on this. By default the browser just looks for this in the cache and doesn't update.

I can use PHP or .htaccess to send various styles of no-cache headers for the config.xml but I don't know if all browsers / flash players will respect them, in particular IE which I've read lots of conflicting information about.

Does any have a definitive answer to this?

Many thanks,

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash Player uses the browser to fetch files, and it is up to the browser to decide if it will use the item in the cache or request it from the server. So any mechanisms you use to tell the browser not to cache the XML should work.

Comment: Thanks Sunil, after all the conflicting information I've read, it's great to get a nice simple answer. Many thanks!